# JQuery getJSON Not Working In External File

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to call jQuery.getJSON in an external JS file but the code is not running when called from index.html. Calling the exact code directly in index.html works fine. Here's the code:

```
    jQuery.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/test', function (json) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(json));
        return;
    });
```

I'm running this code in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Are you loading the external script after you load jQuery?

Comment: http://echo.jsontest.com/test in url where is data ????? this is working fine on my side

Comment: This issue has been resolved. It must have been an environment issue with Visual Studio. I did add the following to my web.config:       <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />